# PHP array multidimensional associative

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

```
$_REQUEST = array(
    'articolo' => array(
        1 => 1,
        3 => 'Sostituzione sostituzioni',
        4 => 'Cambio olio'
    ),
    'specifica' => array(
        1 => 2,
        3 => 'Camoin',
        4 => 'Furgone'
    ),
    'quantita' => array(
        1 => 3,
        3 => 5,
        4 => 7
    )
);
```

i need to insert on database like this

```
$_REQUEST['articolo'][1]
$_REQUEST['specifica'][1]
$_REQUEST['quantita'][1]
```

on database row and

```
$_REQUEST['articolo'][3]
$_REQUEST['specifica'][3]
$_REQUEST['quantita'][3]
```

on another row and ...

```
$_REQUEST['articolo'][4]
$_REQUEST['specifica'][4]
$_REQUEST['quantita'][4]
```

i just want to know how to make another array row by row

i need to print

```
1 -> $_REQUEST['articolo'][1]
2 -> $_REQUEST['specifica'][1]
3 -> $_REQUEST['quantita'][1]

Sostituzione sostituzioni -> $_REQUEST['articolo'][3]
Camoin -> $_REQUEST['specifica'][3]
5 -> $_REQUEST['quantita'][3]

Cambio olio -> $_REQUEST['articolo'][4]
Furgone -> $_REQUEST['specifica'][4]
7 -> $_REQUEST['quantita'][4]
```

thank

Comment: You want to iterate through the array adding items into the database?

Comment: i reiceved that from from fields like $_REQUEST['articolo'][], $_REQUEST['specifica'][], $_REQUEST['quantita'][] and the array is like that i only must to join row by row

Comment: Is it `$request` or `$_REQUEST`?

Answer (score 0):

you need something like this:

```
foreach ($request as $key => $value)
{
    $request[$key][1]   //row1
    $request[$key][3]   //row2
    $request[$key][4]   //row3
}
```

**Edit Based on the comments:**
if the array is dynamic(you do not know the keys of the sub-array), you can do this instead:

```
foreach ($request as $key => $value)
{
    foreach ($request[$key] as $key2 => $value2)
    {
       $request[$key][$key2] //here are your values
    }
}
```

Now you have an idea on how to do it right? use those values inside that `foreach` to add data to your database

Comment: [1][2][3] are variables i don't know every time the number

Comment: i need to print

    1 -> $_REQUEST['articolo'][1]
    2 -> $_REQUEST['specifica'][1]
    3 -> $_REQUEST['quantita'][1]
    
    Sostituzione sostituzioni -> $_REQUEST['articolo'][3]
    Camoin -> $_REQUEST['specifica'][3]
    5 -> $_REQUEST['quantita'][3]
    
    Cambio olio -> $_REQUEST['articolo'][4]
    Furgone -> $_REQUEST['specifica'][4]
    7 -> $_REQUEST['quantita'][4]

Answer (score 0):

```
$name = array_keys($_REQUEST);
$index = array_keys($_REQUEST['articolo']);

for($i=0; $i < count($index); $i++):
    if($i + 1 % count($index)):
        for($j=0; $j < count($name); $j++):
            echo $name[$j].': '.$_REQUEST[$name[$j]][$index[$i]].'<br>'."\n";
        endfor;
        echo '<hr>';
    endif;
endfor;
```

output it's right now

articolo: 1
specifica: 2
quantita: 3

articolo: Sostituzione sotituzioni
specifica: Camoin
quantita: 5

articolo: Cambio olio
specifica: Furgone
quantita: 7

now just need to insert the ordinate data on database